# Standardize some columns in Python Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, sklearn-pandas, standardized

Python code below only return me an array, but I want the scaled data to replace the original data.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
df = StandardScaler().fit_transform(df[['cost', 'sales']])
df
```

output

```
array([[ 1.99987622, -0.55900276],
       [-0.49786658, -0.45658181],
       [-0.5146864 , -0.505097  ],
       [-0.48104676, -0.47814412],
       [-0.50627649,  1.9988257 ]])
```

original data

```
id  cost    sales   item
1   300       50    pen
2   3         88    bottle
3   1         70    drink
4   5         80    cup
5   2        999    ink
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Simply assign it back

```
df[['cost', 'sales']] = StandardScaler().fit_transform(df[['cost', 'sales']])
df
Out[45]: 
   id      cost     sales    item
0   1  1.999876 -0.559003     pen
1   2 -0.497867 -0.456582  bottle
2   3 -0.514686 -0.505097   drink
3   4 -0.481047 -0.478144     cup
4   5 -0.506276  1.998826     ink
```

Answer (score 3):

Or in case the **column index** is used instead of the column names:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
df = pd.DataFrame({"cost": [300,3,1,5,2], "sales": [50,88,70,80,999], "item": ["pen","bottle","drink","cup","ink"]})

# Scale selected columns by index
df.iloc[:, 0:2] = StandardScaler().fit_transform(df.iloc[:, 0:2])

       cost     sales    item
0  1.999876 -0.559003     pen
1 -0.497867 -0.456582  bottle
2 -0.514686 -0.505097   drink
3 -0.481047 -0.478144     cup
4 -0.506276  1.998826     ink
```

The sclaer object **can also be saved** so to scale "new data" based on the existing scaler:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"cost": [300,3,1,5,2], "sales": [50,88,70,80,999], "item": ["pen","bottle","drink","cup","ink"]})
df_new = pd.DataFrame({"cost": [299,5,12,64,2], "sales": [55,99,48,20,999], "item": ["pen","bottle","drink","cup","ink"]})

# Set up scaler
scaler = StandardScaler().fit(df.iloc[:, 0:2])

# Scale original data
df.iloc[:, 0:2] = scaler.transform(df.iloc[:, 0:2])

# Scale new data 
df_new.iloc[:, 0:2] = scaler.transform(df_new.iloc[:, 0:2])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `scale` to standardize specific columns:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import scale
cols = ['cost', 'sales']
df[cols] = scale(df[cols])
```

`scale` subtracts the mean and divides by the sample standard deviation for each column.

Example

```
# Prep
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import scale

# Sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'cost':[300, 3, 1, 5, 2],
    'sales':[50, 88, 70, 80, 999],
    'item': ['pen', 'bottle', 'drink', 'cup', 'ink']
})

# Standardize columns
cols = ['cost', 'sales']
df[cols] = scale(df[cols])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the [benefits of an sklearn Pipeline](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/compose.html#pipeline-chaining-estimators) (convenience/encapsulation, joint parameter selection, and safety from leakage), you can use a `ColumnTransformer`:

```py
preproc = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ('scale', StandardScaler(), ["cost", "sales"]),
    ],
    remainder="passthrough",
)
```

(there are several ways to specify which columns go to the scaler, check [the docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html)).  Now you have the benefit of saving the scaler object as [@Peter mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65832595/10495893), but also you don't have to keep repeating the slicing:

```py
df = preproc.fit_transform(df)
df_new = preproc.transform(df)
```