# Scale specific columns in pandas dataframe using MinMaxScaler

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, rescale

I want to rescale my pandas dataframe using sklearn's MinMaxScaler function, like in [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-scale-pandas-dataframe-columns/) tutorial.

The data I have is in `mydata`,

```
            x1   x2   x3  x4    x5  
Date                                                                 
2015-03-01  90  180  113  12  2125   
2015-03-02  64  180  107   5  2121   
2015-03-03  79  170  110  12  2009   
2015-03-04  82  160  107   6  2020   
2015-03-05  69  152  108  13  1979   
2015-03-06  51  229   95  10  2120
```

and my code to only rescale columns `x1`, `x2`, `x3` is

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler, StandardScaler

### load mydata

scaler = MinMaxScaler()

mydata_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(mydata.values)
mydata_scaled = pd.DataFrame(mydata_scaled, columns=['x1','x2','x3'])

mydata_scaled.head(5)
```

but I get an error `ValueError: Shape of passed values is (5, 6), indices imply (3, 6)`. There is another [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43834242/sklearn-minmaxscaler-scale-specific-columns-only) using `Column_Transformer`, but I want to know why the `MinMaxScaler` method doesn't work.

Comment: you have 5 columns, but you are only providing names for 3 of them in your final dataframe

Comment: so is there a way to specify that I only want to normalize the columns `x1`, `x2`, `x3`? I don't want to touch the other columns

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution:

```
mydata[['x1','x2','x3']] = MinMaxScaler().fit_transform(mydata[['x1','x2','x3']])
```

It's similar to the solution in [Standardize some columns in Python Pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49641707/standardize-some-columns-in-python-pandas-dataframe)